# How can I speed up DNS Record Set updates taking effect?

Tags: domain-name-system

I recently changed our DNS record sets and updated the CNAMEs and IPs. For example,
I am now forwarding `web.xyz.com` to `prod.xyz.com`.

I understand  that these changes may take hours to take effect because the DNS stores the values for 24-48 hours (or whatever the TTL is). I want the changes to take effect faster (or ideally immediately). What can I do to achieve this? For reference, I am using Cloud DNS for this.

UPDATE: I want to know if there is a way to do this AFTER changes are made. Ideally, one would reduce TTL before making the changes so this is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

`I understand that these changes may take hours to take effect because the DNS stores the values for 24-48 hours. I want the changes to take effect faster (or ideally immediately). What can I do to achieve this?`

Well... it will take as long as the TTL that's configured for those records... and only for DNS clients that have those records cached already. If the TTL is 2 hours then it will take 2 hours. If the TTL is 48 hours then it will take 48 hours. If a DNS client doesn't have those records cached already then they'll get the new data immediately upon querying your DNS servers. If you want to reduce the amount of time that the record is cached then lower the TTL of the record.

Comment: That's what I figured AFTER I made the change. I wonder if there's a way to "flush" so it refreshes immediately without waiting the full period of the TTL. In future, I think reducing the TTL before making a change makes sense.

Comment: @Jorjani You may have a way of flushing *your own* cache, but there is no way to do so for everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

DNS propagation delay is based on the last access to the domain and the TTL value set for tgat particular RR (resource record). If the resolver is unable to find an entry in it's cache, it will start querying from root servers till the authoritative name servers for that requested resource. When non authoritative DNS servers look up your domain, they cache the record for n hunderds of seconds so that they don't have to do another lookup for subsequent requests defined by ttl value.
Though this is the case, unless the resource that had a change recently was being served very frequently via that resolver, the changes will get reflected very soon, in a matter of few hours. The most problems occure due to proxy or local browser caches. The worst case scenarios require 12 - 48 hours, in my experience. So, the quick answer is no, but it depends. If you can change name servers at requester side, it will make the process quicker for them.

The rule of thumb for DNS RR modifications is to decrease the TTL value before hand to allow room for the upcoming changes take effect quickly. Once the changes are made, it's the local resolver at the user's end, which determines how to perform the name resolution.

On a side note, the TTL values are usually set for few hours, by default in most cases.